# Access to Excel via VBA to specific sheet whilst overwriting a variable record list

Tags: excel, export

new to stackoverflow and need a little advice on modifying this code to include the deletion of records further than the exported range when exporting from Access to a specific excel worksheet:

Query to extract all Access data from = Stocklist
Spreadsheet to paste data to (inc headings) = G:\Project\test1.xlsx
Worksheet to extract to is also named "Stocklist" and the range is A1 onwards - there are four columns of data that need overwritten by the updated list which is derived from the query.

The following selects the correct file and overwrites the range A1 onwards:

```
Public Sub Export()

Dim rstName As Recordset
Set rstName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Stocklist")

Dim objApp As Object, objMyWorkbook As Object, objMySheet As Object, objMyRange As Object

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objMyWorkbook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\Project\test1.xlsx")
Set objMySheet = objMyWorkbook.Worksheets("Stocklist")
Set objMyRange = objMySheet.Cells(objApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)

With objMyRange
 rstName.MoveFirst 
 .Clear
 .CopyFromRecordset rstName
End With
```

This is great if the data is the same size or larger, but if its smaller it leaves the items outside the pasted/exported range in the list (eg range of 400 records will leave all records after 400 present after overwrite. Is there any way to clear the sheet before the data is added?

Also how transferable is excel macro VBA code as I have some validation rules and error handling in other spreadsheets that I would like to add (eg. check file is not open, return msgbox etc)

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
objMySheet.UsedRange.Clear

With objMyRange
 rstName.MoveFirst 
 .Clear
 .CopyFromRecordset rstName
End With
```